# Event at specific percentage of a ProgressBar in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Good evening.

I was wondering if it is possible to fire an event if a progressbar reaches a specific percentage.

For example: once a progressbar reaches 90% of its value, it will trigger a messagebox to pop up.

I use the **ProgressBar** to compare two times with each other. I can input a time in a **DateTimePicker** that will compare it to my local desktop time. I click a **Button** that will enable a **Timer** and starts comparing these times. The minimum and maximum value is always different since I'm comparing times, so how do I fire an event each time the progressbar reaches 90%?

As you might have noticed, English is not my primary language, so it'll be easier to understand using the code I use now:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim value As Integer = ProgressBar1.Maximum - GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)
        If value > ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ProgressBar1.Value = value

    End Sub

    Public Function GetTimeDifference(ByVal EndTime As DateTime, ByVal StartTime As DateTime) As Integer

        Dim span As TimeSpan = EndTime.TimeOfDay - StartTime.TimeOfDay
        Dim result As Integer = CInt(span.TotalSeconds)

        Return result

    End Function
```

Thanks,
Jordy.

Comment: It is your code that sets the Value property.  So of course you can also add the statements to show the message box.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need an event so much as just a variable to check if you hit 90% or not:

```
Private overNinety As Boolean = False
```

Inside your tick method:

```
ProgressBar1.Value = value

If Not overNinety AndAlso ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum * 0.9 Then
  overNinety = True
  'Do your thing here...
End If
```